# Download a file using Camel based on a url in an SQS message

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to use Camel to read an XML message off an SQS queue, pull out a URL from a specific node in the XML, and download the file at that URL to a specific directory.

I am using the Spring DSL.

The XML message looks something like this:

```
<command>
    <path>http://example.com/myfile/here?q=something&param=somethingelse</path>
    <....>
</command>
```

How can I make this happen? (I could write a Processor to read the SQS message and download the file, but it seems like this should be possible using native Camel components).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about use [splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) and [camel-http](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) component to download the files.

The route could like this

```
from("aws:xxx").split().xtokenize("//path", 't').to("direct:http");

from("direct:http").setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple(${body}).setBody(constant(null).to("http://example.com");
```

If using the Spring DSL, it would look like this

```
<route id="get-download-url">
  <from uri="aws:xxx"/>
  <split>
    <xtokenize mode="t">//path</xtokenize>
  </split>
  <to uri="direct:http"/>
</route>
<route id="download-file">
  <from uri="direct:http"/>
  <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpUri">
    <simple>${body}</simple>
  </setHeader>
  <setBody><simple></simple></setBody>
  <to uri="http://example.com"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to how this might work?